# View helper: classBinding if boolean is false

Tags: ember.js

How can I bind a class to a view with the #view helper, if a boolean is FALSE?

```html
// this is working
{{#view App.MyView controllerBinding="this" classBinding="controller.content.isActive"}}
    <div>test</div>
{{/view}}

// and this is what i want:
{{#view App.MyView controllerBinding="this" classBinding="!controller.content.isActive:is-not-active"}}
    <div>test</div>
{{/view}}
```

I want to bind `is-not-active` as a class name to the view, if `controller.content.isActive` is false.

I can make an simple inverter function on the view, but I there is a better way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The Pull Request has been merged, so you can add a class for a `false` value like this:

```html
{{#view App.MyView controllerBinding="this"
   classBinding="controller.content.isActive:is-active:is-not-active"}}
{{/view}}
```

If you don't want to add a class if the value is `true`, you can use the following syntax:

```html
{{#view App.MyView controllerBinding="this"
   classBinding="controller.content.isActive::is-not-active"}}
{{/view}}
```

---

I would create a property on the view (like you already do with your inverter) and bind to this:

**Handlebars**:

```html
{{#view App.MyView controllerBinding="this" classBinding="isNotActive"}}
    <div>test</div>
{{/view}}
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    isNotActive: Ember.Binding.not('controller.content.isActive')
});
```

---

I've create a [Pull Request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/732) which has not yet been merged but it addresses this issue and would solve it similar to this:

```html
{{#view App.MyView controllerBinding="this"
   classBinding="controller.content.isActive:is-active:is-not-active"}}
    <div>test</div>
{{/view}}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I mean with an "inverter". I will use this now and hope for the Pull Request.