# With Ember's action helper, is bind-attr the only way to set CSS styles?

Tags: ember.js

With the deprecation of the Ember.Button view (w/ recent Ember trunk version) in favor of the action helper, is there a way to set the static/unchanging CSS styling of the action helper's parent HTML element (whether that element is a button, link, etc.) without those static CSS styles being bonked/overwritten?  That is,

- With the old Ember.Button and #view we could pass in both class (for static CSS styles) and classBinding (for dynamic CSS styles) and the static styles would be unaffected by the dynamic ones.
- But with the new action helper, classBinding doesn't seem to work.  bind-attr does work, but any CSS classes specified for that element outside of bind-attr will be overwritten by the bind-attr class="foo" specification.
- Thus, the only way I've found to keep static CSS styles on elements using the action helper is to specify a string property (within the relevant Ember View) specifying the CSS static styles needed.  e.g. {{bind-attr class="App.TheView.isActive App.TheView.cssStyles}}  This is inelegant/leaky.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also mix both static and dynamic styles in the `{{bind-attr}}`, like this:

```
{{bind-attr class=":staticStyle view.someProperty:dynamicStyle}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works!  Did you know this by the docs, or reading the Ember source, or...?

Comment: I don't exactly remember, but there is something in the doc, and then following the issues/PR on the site. For now the complete feature of class bindings is even better. see http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/nGfUp/#base. Following emberjs questions on SO is helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428887/view-helper-classbinding-if-boolean-is-false

Answer (score 1):

How are you using the action helper? You should be able to give the HTML element a class.

```
<a {{action "testIt"}} class="test">testing</a>
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/A9VZS/

Comment: Thanks, I should've included an example.  I forked your snippet to show the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/limist/9cct5/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can now use inline `if`.  `bind-attr` is [deprecated in 1.13](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_legacy-code-bind-attr-code).

```
<div class={{if isUrgent 'is-urgent'}}>
```

New docs are [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/binding-element-class-names/#toc_conditional-values).