# How to bindAttr class when class is defined

Tags: ember.js

In view I'd like to bind some class, but this element should also has defined other class.
I look for some solution but don't find anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/eTcDu/16/

Does some know any solution of this problem?

Comment: just FYI, other linked questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693947/with-embers-action-helper-is-bindattr-the-only-way-to-set-css-styles/11699323#11699323 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428887/view-helper-classbinding-if-boolean-is-false

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And again I found my solution after write question:

[Append a dynamic class to a view having a static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506206/append-a-dynamic-class-to-a-view-having-a-static-class)

```
{{bindAttr class=":staticStyle view.someProperty:dynamicStyle}}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, was not aware of that.

Comment: I noticed that this is missing from the documentation: http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_binding-class-names-with-bindattr